What is the meaning of retrieved paper?
What is the meaning of "retrieved journal" ? Can a retrieved article be cited in a paper? The article has a publication date (2018), but it has been written "retrieved 2024". I do not know these terms.

Is "retrieved from the journal" a translation? What is the context in which you are finding this phrase?

It is from the journal. It is not a translation

Could you link to the the context? From what you've written 'retrieved' might just mean 'downloaded' but it's not very clear.

@Anyon, you are right, it means "downloaded". Many thanks

If you look at any paper from that journal, do they all say "retrieved 2024"? In that case it is probably just printing today's date as the date you retrieved/downloaded/viewed the paper. When things are cited from web pages, it's common to report what date that content was retrieved since content on the web can change over time. It's a bit weird to add a retrieved date to a journal article, maybe less weird for a preprint archive or similar where there is an expectation that content may change.

"Retrieved" means you accessed the article on that date. For example if I cite:
Yating Yang, 'Divorce pals': new China trend sees single mothers team up, live together, share resources, South China Morning Post, 16 June 2024 (retrieved 19 June 2024)
Then I am saying that the article was written on 16 June 2024, and I accessed it on 19 June 2024. If the author makes changes to the article next month, then the specific claim I am citing might no longer be in the article.

I believe that the main purpose of stating when the article was accessed is to indicate when the link to access the article was last found to work correctly. The article does not typically change, whereas links frequently do.
